# Python DistributionNotFound Error after installing EB CLI 3.0

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Have tried many things, but keep getting this error after multiple attempts to update python, pip, etc.  I am on OS X running 10.9.5.

```
CMD% eb 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/eb", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: python-dateutil>=2.1,<3.0.0
```

Comment: None of the solutions worked for me, and I'm getting the same error. Strange.

Answer (score 22):

I was experiencing a similar error when trying to run eb, though not for dateutil...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "/usr/local/bin/eb", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point   
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)   
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))   
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: requests>=2.6.1,<2.7
```

For me the solution was to update setuptools:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Hope that helps somebody.

Comment: This worked solving the issue in Ubuntu 12.04, whereas the same setup on Mac OS was working.

It upgraded setuptools from 0.6rc11 to 18.2.

Answer (score 13):

Use the following command:

```
pip install awsebcli
```

It will automatically upgrade all dependecies of awsebcli.

Comment: This worked for me in mac osx after i updated the command like sudo pip install awsebcli

Answer (score 7):

use the following command

```
sudo pip install python-dateutil
```

to upgrade it

Comment: This one worked for me. Try it if the other ones don't.

Answer (score 2):

Pip is probably linked to a different version of python then standard.

You should try installing pip using

```
python get-pip.py
```

(You can download get-pip.py from the pip website)

Otherwise, You can see which Python everything is linked too.

```
which python

head -1 $(which eb)

head -1 $(which pip)
```

You can change to shebang line in the eb script to match pip and it should all work.

You can also install using a `virtualenv` (pythons recommended way of installing)

```
virtualenv ~/ebenv
source ~/ebenv/bin/activate
pip install awsebcli
deactivate
sudo ln -s ~/ebenv/bin/eb /usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case on mac osx 10.10, I had to reinstall.

```
sudo pip install python-dateutil
```

Just in case some runs into this type of error. check the last paragraph in the trace for the kind of error that it is being raised. In my case, this was:

```
 raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (six 1.4.1
(/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python),
Requirement.parse('six>=1.5'), set(['python-dateutil']))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, for me, the eb script was using the wrong python. To solve it I just modified the eb script:

```
> which eb
/usr/local/bin/eb
> sudo vim /usr/local/bin/eb
## Change the first line from '#!/usr/bin/python' to '#!/usr/local/bin/python'
```

After restarting the terminal, everything work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

From the raised error in your log, it needs `python-dateutil>=2.1`.
So you need to make sure that version is installed and install it if not. I had similar issue, and the solution (in my case) is:

```
 $ pip install --ignore-installed python-dateutil==2.2
```